# correcting javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The browser debugging console is stating:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $('#cartitems').html  [line break inserted for SO question]
  ("<span class='smaller cartitem_added'>Pancetta Tesa Natura - kg x 0.1 => € 1,15</span>");
  $('#cartitems_count').html("12");
```

yet the page is rendering the div appropriately.  The procedure is running in a rails 4 application from a form defined with

```
<%= form_for(Cartitem.new, remote: true, html: {class: 'new_cartitem', id: 'data-js-cartitem-form'}, data: {'js-cartitem-form' => true}) do |f| %>
```

jQuery is installed and invoking the following

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('[data-js-cartitem-form]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var cartitem = $(xhr.responseText).hide();
    $('#cartitems').append(cartitem);
    cartitem.fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById('cartitems').reset();
  });

  $('#cartitems').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var cartitem_id = xhr.responseJSON.id;
    $('[data-js-cartitem-id=' + cartitem.id + ']').hide();
  });

});
```

The console is pointing to `body=1:3` of the file that contains the above javascript.

Where is the syntax mistake?

Comment: First try removing `$('#cartitems').append(cartitem);` from the jquery code block and try see if error still persist.

Comment: It looks like the error is in a different file. Look for the file which has the `$('#cartitems_count').html` part in it.